# How does `flip id` work?

Tags: haskell

Why is `flip id` accepted as valid expression? Shouldn't it fail at type check of `a` against `b -> c`?

```
Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
Prelude> :t id
id :: a -> a
Prelude> :t flip id
flip id :: b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

Comment: It'll be obvious once you realize that `($)` is the same as `id`, just with a more specific type.

Answer (score 13):

The point is that

```
id :: a -> a
```

for *any* type `a`, including function types. That is, we can choose `a = (b -> c)` and obtain

```
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

which, since `->` associates to the right, is typically written as

```
id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
```

The above can be interpreted as a function taking two arguments: the first of type `b -> c` and the second of type `b`. So we can `flip` it.

Answer (score 2):

The `a`s in the type of `id` can match *any* type, in particular, `(b->c)`.

```
Prelude> :t id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c) :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
```

The `->` is right-associative, so we can drop the rightmost set of parens

```
Prelude> :t id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
```

Making id into a two-argument function.